# Published Google Play Store App not doing authentication but debug apk passes authentication

Tags: django, ionic-framework, google-play-console, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, android-app-signing

Assistance please.

I am doing an app in ionic framework with JWT authentication coming from Django rest framework and encountering a very weird problem, before I upload my app to Google play console it is able to login successfully but when I download the Open Test Version of Google play store am unable to login

After some hours of research am thinking the problem is related to app signing and something to deal with API integrity.

I have tried to upload my keystore file that I generated using keytool to Google Play Console's App Signing Tab under App Integrity then also associated my app with the Digital Asset Links JSON but still encounter the same issue.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you signing the apk using Android Studio before uploading? Ensure that you are building the app in Production mode when building with Ionic/Capacitor. And If you have different configurations with different API endpoints, check that the configuration you are building is pointing to the correct endpoint. I have made that mistake many times!